# Postgres searching through arrays within JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

Many similar questions, but unfortunately non helped me solve my problem. I tried to && and @> and similar, but no success.

I have a postgres DB with a table, that has a "value" column typed "json". All rows have the same basic structure, a simple JSON object, with the att "value" holding an array of strings:

```
{
   value: ['one', 'two', 'three']
}
```

I need to make a query accepting an array of strings and returns all the rows, in which the value array and the passed array of strings have at least one common element.

Following the upper example, if I send ['one', 'four'], it should return the row with value: ['one', 'two', 'three'], since there is an intersection - 'one'.

If I send the array ['four', 'five', 'six'], it will not return this row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `?|` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for that. But as you are using `json` and not the recommended `jsonb` type, you need to cast your column:

```
select *
from the_table
where (value::jsonb -> 'value') ?| array['one', 'four']
```